# No matching function for call in class template specialization for a pointer type

Tags: c++, template-specialization

I don't know why a pointer cannot be passed to a function as a reference. Perhaps I'm missing the point of the error.

```
class Point{
public:
    Point(){}
};

template<typename KEY,typename VALUE>
class TemplTest{
public:
    TemplTest(){}
    bool Set(const KEY& key,const VALUE& value){
        return false;
    }
};

template<typename KEY,typename VALUE>
class TemplTest<KEY*,VALUE>{
public:
    TemplTest(){}
    bool Set(KEY*& key,const VALUE& value){
        return true;
    }
};

int main(){
    Point p1;
    TemplTest<Point*,double> ht;
    double n=3.14;
    ht.Set(&p1,n);

    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
no matching function for call to 'TemplTest<Point*, double>::Set(Point*, double&)'
no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Point*' to 'Point*&'
```

Please help, thanks!

Comment: Look at this -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492523/no-known-conversion-from-pointer-to-reference-to-pointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because reference cannot be bind to rvalue, `&p1` is a rvalue with no name, to get around this

```
Point *p1_ptr = &p1;
Point *&p1_ptr_ref = p1_ptr;
ht.Set( p1_ptr_ref, n);
```

or you can add `const` to key

```
    bool Set( KEY* const& key,const VALUE& value){
//                 ^^^^^
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks you very much. To me it's strange, I must have a look at those rvalues.